# Using a .dll file in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, dll, flash-builder

I need to use a dll file that was created in C# within my FlashBuilder project.  I saw that adobe native extensions might be able to be used to incorporate the dll file, but I'm not entirely sure how to make the .ane file from the .dll file.  I was wondering if there is an easier way to gain access to the classes and functions inside the dll file within my actionscript code.

Thanks,

Ilithis

Comment: sorry. there is no easier way

Answer (score 1):

Native extensions may only be used if you're working in Adobe Air.  You can read more about the topic and find tutorials [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html?PID=4176632).